# How to include ember-template-compiler.js when using ember-source

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-cli

After migration to node `ember-source` from bower `ember` package our build is failing with missing `ember-template-compiler.js` which was part of the bower package. How to include it from `ember-source` npm package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found answer myself:

Exchange import of `ember-template-compiler.js` in `ember-cli-build.js`

**from**

```
app.import('bower_components/ember/ember-template-compiler.js');
```

**to**

```
app.import('vendor/ember/ember-template-compiler.js');
```

**more on topic**

https://simplabs.com/blog/2017/02/13/npm-libs-in-ember-cli.html